# How to Set an empty Custom Country Field from SOAP request in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to set empty or blank value on a custom field (List/Record Type) of item which is targeting NetSuite Country List using NetSuite SOAP Request but not able to do so.

```
            List<CustomFieldRef> arrCustomField = new List<CustomFieldRef>();

            ListOrRecordRef rec = new ListOrRecordRef();
            rec.internalId = "";

            SelectCustomFieldRef dcfselect = new SelectCustomFieldRef();
            dcfselect.scriptId = "custitem_countryoforigin";
            dcfselect.value = rec;
            arrCustomField.Add(dcfselect);

            setObjectProperty("customFieldList", item, arrCustomField.ToArray());
```

As ssen rec.internalid is empty while this is not working, same i have passed rec.internalid with null/0/-1, which is also not working.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

(1) For custom Fields (List type/Select) use as below tags in SOAP request

<ns9:location internalId="null"/>

OR

(2) Use nullFieldList tag.Please see the code below

```html
<soap:Body>
   <platformMsgs:update>
      <platformMsgs:record internalId="373" xsi:type="listRel:Customer">
         <platformCore:nullFieldList xsi:type="platformCore:NullField">
            <platformCore:name>custEntity9</platformCore:name>
         </platformCore:nullFieldList>
      </platformMsgs:record>
   </platformMsgs:update>
</soap:Body>
```

For custom fields (Free form Text), you can pass null/blank values like this :

```html
<customField xsi:type="StringCustomFieldRef" scriptId="custcol_billing_rule_type">
                <value/>
```